# Tracking a conversation in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

Background: I have been working with twitter API. Have it setup so that when someone mentions/messages me, it gets sent to a chatbot. Bot make reply, I tweet it out using API.
Each tweet has a unique `status_id` in addition to a field called `rep_to_stat_id` so a conversation looks like this:

```
person 'hi how are you?'          stat_id = 1 rep_to_stat_id = blank
    me 'ok, and you?'             stat_id = 2 rep_to_stat_id = 1
person 'are you stalking me'      stat_id = 3 rep_to_stat_id = 2
    me 'no you are stalking me'   stat_id = 4 rep_to_stat_id = 3
```

etc.

When I send to bot first time, make a random converstation ID (`conv_id`) so the bot can track the conversation.

Problem is tracking this, it's like a ladder, leading up to the original `stat_id` with no `rep_to_stat_id`, and has to include the common `conv_id`.

Up until now I have always had tables with a one to many type setup, I cannot get my head around what type of structure this is.

Is there an option in mysql to add to query to follow a ladder of each conversation to its first/last point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to store hierarchical data in relational databases.

One of the most common ways is to simply have a table with all the columns you mentioned (`stat_id`, `rep_to_stat_id` [nullable], and `conv_id`). The problem is, to retrieve the full tree up to the root node, you'd need a recursive function (in MySQL or your scripting language of choice), making several queries.

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database) should give you a nice overview of all the available options for modelling your tree structure.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for - ' hierarchical data'. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Have one column tag the conversation_id, and another that tracks the iteration *within* that conversation.

```
person    text                       conversation_id    reply_num
------------------------------------------------------------------
0         "Hi"                       0                  0
1         "Hello, who are you"       0                  1
0         "I am a bot"               0                  2
1         "Goodbye"                  0                  3
0         "Hi"                       1                  0           //new conversation thread
1         "who is this?"             1                  1
0         "This is a bot"            1                  2
1         "leave me alone"           1                  3
```